# Which container for a KeyValuePair, sorted by the keys distance to another transform, and allowing the value to be changed during runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The key is a gameobject, and the list should be actively sorted during gameplay depending on distance to the gameobject which contains the list.

The value is an enum, which can be changed during gameplay; so therefore it can not be readonly.

I have been messing around with Dictionary, SortedList, and a List of KeyValuePairs, but I keep running into problems with each for different reasons.

So, which container fits what I am trying to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems you ran into?

Comment: List of KeyValuePairs seemed like it fit the best, but it is readonly and I had a hard time figuring out how to remove an entry, although I know its possible. So just not sure if List of KeyValuePairs is what would be recommended.

Comment: SortedDictionary is also available, but works exactly the same way as SortedList on the user side, except for some performance issues. Your problem might instead of using GameObjects as keys. GameObjects do some very weird stuff, like returning true when comparing to null. You might want to use unique IDs for your GameObjects to use as keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how and what for exactly you need the result ...

[`Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) implements `IEnumrable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` so you could e.g. use Linq [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderByDescending__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__) (or maybe [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) depending on your needs) and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)

```
using System.Linq;

...

Dictionary<GameObject, SomeEnum> GameObjectToValue = new Dictionary<GameObject, SomeEnum>();

private List<SomeEnum> GetDecendingValues()
{
    return 
        // this first query returns an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<GameObject, SomeEnum>>
        // which is sorted descending by the distance (furthest = first element, closest = last)
        // from the THE_VECTOR_TO_COMOPARE_TO
        GameObjectToValue.OrderByDescending(kvp => Vector3.Distance(kvp.Key.transform.position, THE_VECTOR_TO_COMOPARE_TO)

        // In this second step you say you only want the values as IEnumerable<SomeEnum>
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Value)

        // And finaly you convert it again to a list (if needed)
        .ToList();
}
```

or if you still want it as a sorted dictionary the change is very small:

```
private Dictionary<GameObject, SomeEnum> GetDecendingDictionary()
{
    return 
        // the sorting stays the same
        GameObjectToValue.OrderByDescending(kvp => Vector3.Distance(kvp.Key.transform.position, THE_VECTOR_TO_COMOPARE_TO)
        // convert the IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<GameObject, SomeEnum>>
        // back to a dictionary
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

---

What you see here are [`=>` lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). Basically it's an iterator expression so it always means you "iterate" or if you want so "loop" over a list/enumration (`IEnumerable`).

For example

```
.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

under the hood means something similar to

```
// Ofcourse it uses an IEnumerable not a List but this 
// is just for better understanding where the kvp variable comes from
var list = new List<SomeEnum>();
foreach(var kvp in theSortedeyValuePairEnumerable)
{
    list.Add(kvp.Value);
}
```